# How to find out what parameter was passed to a Windows Service

Tags: windows, windows-service

How do you find out what parameter was passed when starting a Windows service?

I usually start a service thru `net start` by passing parameters as shown below

```
net start DocumentHashService /Recursive /Count:500
```

`services.msc` does not list what parameters a service was started with.
Is there a way to view the parameters passed?

Answer (score 2):

[process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) should tell you this in the command line view. See the link for details

Comment: It is weird.  For some services or applications, "Command Line" column does show parameters but not for the service I am running...

Answer (score 1):

Normally the only reliable way is to modify the service to report or log the parameters. As this is likely not possible you can temporarily replace the service executable with one which does report the parameters. You can grab a very simple executable intended specifically for this task from [here](http://www.gardeniers.com/files/Args.exe). Once you have gathered the information you require replace the executable with the original.

Answer (score 0):

From within services.msc you can open the properties of a service and look for `Path to executable:` which has the entire launch string underneath, including parameters the system uses when firing it up

Here's a screenshot from the web that shows a parameter of: -sSQL2005
[alt text http://www.sqlstudy.com/stimages/sql-2005-services-en.jpg](http://www.sqlstudy.com/stimages/sql-2005-services-en.jpg)

Comment: That path is read out of the registry and has nothing to do with parameters passed on with net start, which is what the question is about.