# NET START command not passing parameters in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, service

My application calls a Stored Procedure, through the stored procedure I am calling a Windows Service using the `NET START` command as follows:

```
SELECT @Cmd = 'Net Start ServiceName /"' + @param1 + '" /"' + @param2 + '"'
```

Now the parameters passed here are not reaching the `OnStart` method. These values are blank.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
Try
service1= New Service
service1.param2 = args(1)
service1.param1 = args(0)
```

Here I get `args(0)` as the name of service instead of the value that is passed, and `args(1)` is blank.
Although the `args.Getlength(0)` returns 2.

The service starts successfully, it invokes the executable, but the parameters are not there.

What can be the reason?

- Administrative access might be required in `NET START` command?
- Has the syntax changed for `NET START` command in Windows Server 2008?
- Windows Services do not accept parameters in Windows Server 2008?

The same thing is running fine on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 3):

`NET START` doesn't support passing parameters. EDIT: Actually it apparently does pass parameters in some cases as you have stated. I suspect that this behaviour of the NET START command was by accident rather than by design, which is why it no longer works and why the behaviour isn't mentioned [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490713)

Try `sc start` instead, as per this answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/143367/how-to-start-a-service-with-certain-start-parameters-on-windows)

`sc start` also [officially](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742126%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) supports passing parameters.