# In a Windows Service, will the Start Parameters be preserved if the Start is of type "Automatic"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-service

Well the title says it, in a Windows Service, will the Start Parameters be preserved after a reboot if the Start is of type "Automatic"?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. The Service Manager GUI stinks.

If you want to actually save start parameters, then go to `\\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` in the registry. Find your service. You can also enter startup parameters as part of the ImagePath key.

[image]

Comment: thanks, so if I set a service to start automatically from within the UI and set there the start parameters, am I supposed to see these appended to the ImagePath in the registry because I don't. Is there anywhere else in the registry where I can see what parameters were set within the UI? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, in this case, forget the GUI. The GUI sucks. It works for passing in parameters one time, but it will not save them. I'm revising my answer to reflect that. Sorry for the inconvenience.